# WP 8.1 Silverlight App: Where to get WNS "Package SID" and "Client Secret Key" for an existing app?

Tags: silverlight, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, sid

I want to use WNS-Notifications for a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight App, of which there already is a WP 8.0-Version published in the store. 
(The WP 8.0-Version does not use any notification services).

I've got everything working besides the credentials: The Notifications are handled via a Windows RT background task and in the emulator I successfully receive pushes. 
But I still need to get an access token in the app, and as it is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx), in order to get an access token I need the Package SID and the Client Secret Key of the app .

Following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868206.aspx) tutorial didn't work, because the app doesn't have an entry "services" in the WP-Dashboard:

> Step 2: Obtain the identity values for your app [...] 1. Select the Services link.

This seems to work with Win RT-Apps only.

So my question is: How can i obtain Package SID and Client Secret Key with a WP Silverlight App? Do I somehow have to register the App separately in the Windows Store, beside the Windows Phone Store?

Thanks in advance!

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the solution:

- Start a new app submission in the dev center
- Go to "App info" (first entry)
- Reserve a new app name (e.g. "appname_wns"), 
  and voilà, suddenly there appears an entry for "Windows Push Notifications (WNS)" at the bottom of the page.

Also remember to update the Package Identity in the Package.appxmanifest (open it by pressing F7):

```
<Package>
    <Identity Name="PACKAGE_IDENTITY_NAME_FROM_DEV_CENTER" 
              Publisher="WINDOWS_PUBLISHER_NAME_FROM_DEV_CENTER" ... />
    ...
</Package>
```